New home with textured wall and popcorn ceiling. Skim coating?
New home owner here, house has some popcorn ceiling and some textured wall. What is my best option here? Seems like skim coating is the best option. Smooth it out and paint over it.
Ceiling:

Textured wall:


Not sure on the effort here on the painted textured wall. I am also thinking about just keeping it and paint over it but i really don't like as it does not flow with rest of the house.

Depending on the age of the home, start with an asbestos test, popcorn ceilings are one of the commonest items...

A) "Best" is opinion based and you've given us no criteria to determine how to judge "best" - price, ease, simplicity, etc. B) Best option for WHAT? Are you looking for a new color? Are you looking to renovate by complete replacement? Do you want to apply wallpaper so you need a smooth surface? We don't have a clue what you're attempting to do, so recommendations could be all over the place based on random guesses of your end goal.

Unless you have a lot of experience (or want to take the time to develop it on this project) it's normally faster to get to smooth if you attach 1/4" drywall over the textured surface you want to vanish. Since you may not be counting your time as money, you certainly can go the skim-coat route, but it is very likely to take you more time to complete satisfactorily.
Note that texture-by-default is a sign that the wall/ceiling it's on may not be very straight/flat (put a long straightedge on it in several directions) as it's a way to visually disguise defects that will show up with a smooth finish.

Do you think the ceiling is pop corn ceiling or normal textured ceiling? I have people telling me it is not a pop corn ceiling. If it is in fact pop corn then I do want to get it tested.

What year was the home built?

If you put a new layer of drywall over the ceiling, you will have encapsulated whatever the current finish is, at which point I believe you can mostly ignore the asbestos question until/unless you are cutting new holes in the ceiling.
